# How to store exec output to a file?

Tags: c, exec

I have execv("/bin/sh", arguments), which executes shell with arguments as its commands.

I get the output in the terminal but I need to store the same in a file. How can I do so?

I have execv inside a fork call.

For example is if the argument passed to execv is pwd, the program prints present working directory on terminal but I want to redirect the output to file or some buffer so that i can send the same to my client terminal (I'm doing client-server multithreaded programming)

Comment: Could you give some details? I think your exec is within a fork()? Do you need to redirect stdout to a file or send data to both streams? Have you looked at freopen() or dup2()? What are you results so far.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Thanks! Got the answer after looking at dup2 call.

Answer (score 0):

The `*inx` function: `tee` splits the execution path.  Something like:

```
 myExec | tee myFile |  ....
```